# Deriving Fourier inversion formula from Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fourier-analysis

> Let $g\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ (infinitely differentiable with compact support), and let $$\hat{g}(y)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)e^{-ixy}dx$$ Assume that $\hat{g}$ is in the Schwartz class. Prove that $$g(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g}(y)e^{ixy}dy$$
>
> We may use the result that if $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ is a periodic function of period $2L$, then $$\hat{f}(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^Lf(y)e^{-in\pi y/L}dy\right)e^{i\pi nx/L}$$

I'm trying to follow    *Steven Stadnicki*'s hint. Since $g$ has compact support, let $N$ be such that $g(x)=0$ for all $|x|>N$. Choose $L>N$, and let $f_L(x)=g(x)$ for $|x|\leq N$ and extend $f_L(x)$ periodically with period $2L$ to all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then we have $$\hat{f_L}(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \left(\dfrac{1}{2L}\int_{-L}^Lf(y)e^{-in\pi y/L}dy\right)e^{i\pi nx/L}$$

If I send $L$ to $\infty$, in some sense I get the function $g$. But I'm still confused how the Fourier coefficients of $f_L$ will translate to the coefficients of $g$.

Comment: You know that $g()$ has compact support, so in particular there's a $N$ such that $g(x) = 0$ for all $|x|\gt N$.  What if you choose $L\gt N$, and set $f(x) = g(x)$ for $0\leq |x| \leq N$, extended periodically to all of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Then I would get the Fourier coefficients of $f$ in the formula that I mentioned. But how does that imply the coefficients of $g$?

Comment: My thinking was that you ought to be able to (a) show the inner integral 'converging' to the Fourier transform of $g()$, and (b) show the outer sum becoming a Riemann sum for the inverse Fourier transform...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki The inner integral converging as $L\rightarrow\infty$, you mean?

Comment: Mika: precisely.  (You may need to do some rescaling somewhere along the way, of course)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I'm still confused (please see edit). It would be great if you could provide more detail.

Comment: introduce a gaussian term in your proof, and make use of the fact the FT of a gaussian is still a gaussian. @MikaH.

Comment: @freak_warrior I think that would be too complicated to introduce a Gaussian. Is there a simpler way, along the lines of Steven Stadnicki's suggestions?

Comment: Should it really be $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{f_L}$ in the third and fourth displayed equations? I think it should be $f$ and $f_L$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My outline of solution:

Replacing $\hat{g}(y)$ by the integral, we will obtain
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g}(y)e^{ixy}dy=
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(z)e^{iy(x-z)}dz\right)dy$$

Next we multiply a term $e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2y^2}{4}}$ into the integration, and consider the limit as $\epsilon\to0$,

$$A(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}g(z)e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2y^2}{4}}e^{iy(x-z)}dz\right)dy$$
After simplifying, we get
$$A(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g}(y)e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2y^2}{4}}e^{ixy}dy$$
Since $|\hat{g}(y)e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2y^2}{4}}e^{ixy}|\leq|\hat{g}(y)|$,
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0}A(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \hat{g}(y)e^{-\frac{\epsilon^2y^2}{4}}e^{ixy}dy=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{g}(y)e^{ixy}dy$$...

Comment: In case it's not entirely clear to OP: dominated convergence is used here (with logic somewhat backwards from what you might expect).