# Why is a sum being approximated by an integral in part of a derivation of the Fourier inversion formula from the Fourier series formulae?

Tags: calculus, summation, fourier-analysis, proof-explanation, approximation

From the complex Fourier series of general period $L$, $f(x+L)=f(x)$,

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}c_n\exp\left(\frac{2\pi inx}{L}\right)\tag{1}$$

and the coefficients $c_n$ are given by

$$c_n=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(x)\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi inx}{L}\right)\tag{2}$$

combining the formula's $(2)$ and $(1)$ to give a single formula for $f(x)$ yields

$$\begin{align}f(x) &=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(y)\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi iny}{L}\right)dy\right]\exp\left(\frac{2\pi inx}{L}\right)\\ &\color{red}{\approx}\frac{1}{L}\int_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\int_{-L/2}^{L/2}f(y)\exp\left(\frac{-2\pi iny}{L}\right)dy\right]\exp\left(\frac{2\pi inx}{L}\right)dn\end{align}$$

The lecturer noted that this is a is not a rigorous derivation, but even so, I would like to understand why the second equation is an approximation and not an equality.

The lecturer did mention that if $L$ is large the $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi inx}{L}\right)$ varies 'slowly' with $n$, so the discrete variable $n$ can be replaced with a continuous variable $n$ and then the sum becomes an integral. But I still fail to see why this justifies the approximation and not equality.

The reason why I object to the approximation is that we define integrals as limits to sums since we are going from a discrete quantity to a continuous one. Put simply, I have never seen a sum being approximated by an integral before, normally it's the other way round.

Even though this derivation is non-rigorous, is anyone able to explain why the approximation (marked red) is justified?

I have read [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/560788/deriving-fourier-inversion-formula-from-fourier-series), but it still does not address my question here.

Please note, I am not after a rigorous proof, I am just trying to understand the logic behind the approximation used here. Thanks.

Comment: From "I have never seen a sum being approximated by an integral before, normally it's the other way round." I am curious: do you not believe that approximations work both ways?  If two quantities are close enough to call one an approximation of the other, aren't both close enough to call each an approximation to the other?

Comment: @EricTowers "do you not believe that approximations work both ways", no I do not. Or to be a little more precise; I have never came across approximations that 'work both ways'. From calculus, when I see a (discrete) sum I know this to be the approximation and then in the limit (that the discrete variable $\to 0$), the approximate discrete sum is taken to be an integral over a continuous variable, this then ceases to be an approximation and therefore, an equality is used. As per your second question, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "each approximations to the other".

Comment: If two numbers are approximately equal, then either one can be used as an approximation of the other. If you have a sum you don't know how to do and an integral you know is close to it, then you can just as well use the integral to approximate the sum. Anyway, this approximation is justified if the integrand is sufficiently close to being constant for $n$ on each interval $[k-1/2,k+1/2]$ for integers $k$.

Comment: With no restrictions, there is no reason to believe that this will be the case, but it becomes more plausible when $L$ is large, which is the regime in which one can develop the Fourier transform, which I assume is what is going on here.

Comment: @Ian Yes, in the next step of the derivation after substitution of $k=2\pi n/L$ the $L \to \infty$ limit is taken. "If two numbers are approximately equal, then either one can be used as an approximation of the other"; I would love to know what you mean by this, but thank you for your comments.

Comment: It is just what it means to approximate; to replace something by something else that is close to what you started with, generally with the goal of simplifying matters.

Comment: @Ian Okay, so if I am understanding you correctly we replace the sum by an integral and write it with an approximation sign, and we do this just because we are unsure if the integral will be exactly equal to the previous equality. Is this correct?

Comment: Basically, but again for finite $L$ they actually are different values. A different, somewhat more rigorous way to structure the argument is to view $n/L$ (or some fixed multiple thereof) as the continuous variable to begin with, rather than treating $n$ as a continuous variable and then changing variables after doing that.